# How to see library functions available in any Arduino library?

Tags: arduino

When I want to code about lets say zigbee library so how I will come to know that which functions are supported by zigbee object?Please help.

Comment: Have you checked it's library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to know what SoftwareSerial.h provides. Search for it in Arduino directory, e.g.: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino. All public methods are at your disposal.

This applies to already installed libraries into Arduino IDE:

> SoftwareSerial.h:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <Stream.h>
.........
.........
class SoftwareSerial : public Stream
{
private:
  // per object data
  uint8_t _receivePin;
  uint8_t _receiveBitMask;
  volatile uint8_t *_receivePortRegister;
  uint8_t _transmitBitMask;
  volatile uint8_t *_transmitPortRegister;
.........
.........

public:
  // public methods
  SoftwareSerial(uint8_t receivePin, uint8_t transmitPin, bool inverse_logic = false);
  ~SoftwareSerial();
  void begin(long speed);
  bool listen();
  void end();
  bool isListening() { return this == active_object; }
  bool overflow() { bool ret = _buffer_overflow; _buffer_overflow = false; return ret; }
  int peek();

  virtual size_t write(uint8_t byte);
  virtual int read();
  virtual int available();
  virtual void flush();

  using Print::write;

  // public only for easy access by interrupt handlers
  static inline void handle_interrupt();
};
```

Generally open a library header file and all public methods and properties are at your disposal.

Comment: The path depends if the library it was installed with the Arduino IDE or was added after from Arduino IDE menu. For the first is inside of Arduino program folder; in the second case is in the user folder(User\My Documents\Arduino\libraries